# Python use CONNECT http verbs, header manipulation, and TLS/SSL

Tags: python, http, https, proxy, proxies

In Python, how do I use the CONNECT http verb and do http header manipulation, and TLS/SSL?

Unfortunately `requests/urllib` don't support [this](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/07/Python_Requests_And_Proxies/).

Trying to avoid manually doing this with `openssl + sockets`.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a blog post from 2013, which contains a link to a `urllib3` [Github issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/50), which was [fixed about a month later](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/170), and support was added to `requests` [shortly afterward](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/1515), and is there in all 2.x versions.

So, you're looking for a workaround for a problem that was solved almost 5 years ago.

To use an HTTPS proxy, you just [configure it the same way as an HTTP proxy](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:12345',
}
page = requests.get('https://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

If you, e.g., run `nc -kl 1080` on 10.10.1.10, you'll see this:

```
CONNECT example.org:443 HTTP/1.0
```

And if you run an actual HTTPS proxy there, it will just work.

---

You also claim that `urllib` doesn't handle HTTPS proxies, but it *always* has. It's slightly more painful to set up, but still not that hard:

```
ph = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https': '192.168.42.100:1080'})
op = urllib.request.build_opener(p)
page = op.open('https://example.com')
```

… or, if you want to use it for everything rather than a single request:

```
ph = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https': '192.168.42.100:1080'})
urllib.request.install_opener(urllib.request.build_opener(p))
page = urllib.request.open('https://example.com')
```

---

And of course if you have your default proxy settings configured in the appropriate way for your platform, you don't even need to do this much; both `requests` and `urllib` will just use them.